# GitBash to create Git Repository in Network Places?

Tags: git, repository, git-bash

I'm running Windows XP SP 3 on my computer. I know how to use GitBash, but I don't know how to get to my Network Places area within it so that I can create a Git Repository of a folder within a directory of my FTP Site (which is in Network Places).

Basically, the whole point of me creating the Network in Windows XP was so that I can create a Git Repository within a folder on the Network. I thought this would be possible, but maybe now I'm proven wrong in thinking this?

How do I browse to the Network in Network Places that I setup in Windows XP, through GitBash and create a Git Repository in there? Or is there a better way to create a Git Repository within a folder of my site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subst command and associate a drive letter to a path.
However, you cannot use it with an [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

Try to use:

```
net use * \ftp\server\path\to\folder
```

Then in yout git bash, you can:

```
cd /d/...
```

(if `D:\` was the drive letter associated to that path)